# Drag and Drop in a POPUP in Flex 4

Tags: xml, apache-flex, drag-and-drop, popup, advanceddatagrid

I wanto do a simple dragdrop in an advancedDataGrid which is in a popup window. The popup window is inside a Vbox and the Vbox is inside a canvas. The item which will be dragged is inside a Group and is a tree. I giving a link of my code of popup window. If anyone can answer why I cant dragdrop in this window will be a very big help. Thanks in advance :)

Here is the link of my code : http://pastebin.com/KeSYuseJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just setting the dropenable flag in AdvancedDataGrid to false solved my problem. Its because tree and advacnedDataGrid has different data format!